# Creating new column in pandas from values of other column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am dealing with the following dataframe:

```
          p                      q 
   0      11                     2                            
   1      11                     2                  
   2      11                     2                  
   3      11                     3                  
   4      11                     3                  
   5      12                     2                  
   6      12                     2                  
   7      13                     2               
   8      13                     2
```

I want create a new column, say **s**, which starts with 0 and goes on. This new col is based on "p" column, whenever the p changes, the "s" should change too.

For the first 4 rows, the "p" = 11, so "s" column should have values 0 for this first 4 rows, and so on...

Below is the expectant df:

```
     s             p         q 

 0   0             11        2         
 1   0             11        2         
 2   0             11        2          
 3   0             11        2          
 4   1             11        4           
 5   1             11        4           
 6   1             11        4           
 7   1             11        4           
 8   2             12        2           
 9   2             12        2           
 10  2             12        2           
 11  3             12        3           
 12  3             12        3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `diff` with `cumsum` (subtract one if you want the id to start from 0):

```
df["finalID"] = (df.ProjID.diff() != 0).cumsum()
df
```

[image]

*Update*, if you want to take both *voyg_id* and *ProjID* into consideration, you can use a *OR* condition on the two columns difference, so that whichever column changes, you get an increase in the final id.

```
df['final_id'] = ((df.voyg_id.diff() != 0) | (df.proj_id.diff() != 0)).cumsum()
df
```

[image]